# How to trigger ng-click from nesten repeater in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have one nested ng-repeater and inside that repeater I have a input button with a ng-click. This ng-click throws an error saying it's undefined and not a function. I guess this have something to do with the $scope but not sure how to solve it.

Anyone?

Comment: hard to say without seeing your code...

Comment: can you provide a plunker or post your code in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to upgrade the jQuery version included on the site.